Why the transition probability in the master equation approach just the rate$*dt$ for a simple birth process?
I am modeling a process of an exponentially growing population of cells as $\frac{dn}{dt}=\lambda n$. To account for the intrinsic noise in the birth process of these cells, I write down the propensity of the reaction as $\lambda n$ and plug it into the master equation. Doing that means that the transition probability per a single cell is given by
$$T(1\rightarrow2)=\lambda*dt,$$
and the probability for the whole population to increase by one cell is given by
$$T(n\rightarrow n+1)=\lambda*n*dt.$$
My question is why is that? I do not understand why the probability of transition is given simply by the rate of the exponential growth, $\lambda$, times the time step. Is there a way I can formally prove that?

I deleted my answer and response to your comment.  After additional review of your question, I didn't feel comfortable with my answers without understanding additional context underpinning the modelling.  There may be others who are more familiar and will respond, but I didn't want to add any confusion in the meantime.  Apologies and thanks.

Transition rates are defined as the following limit
$$W(n\to n+\Delta n)=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0 } \frac{P\,(n+\Delta n,t+\Delta t|n,t)}{\Delta t}.$$
Where $P(n',t'|n,t)$ is the probability to find the process in state $n'$ at time $t'$ given that the process was in state $n$ at time $t$. You can write the master equation for the evolution of $P$ in terms of the transition rates,
$$\partial_t P(n,t) = \sum_{\Delta n} W(n-\Delta n\to n)P(n-\Delta n,t)-W(n\to n+\Delta n)P(n,t).$$
Note that the $W\cdot \Delta t$, which is your definition for $T$ is only a true probability in the limit $\Delta t\to 0$. For finite $\Delta t$, $W\cdot \Delta t$ only stands for an approximation to the faithful probability.
In your process there is only one possible transition, which is the spontaneous division of one agent into two agents. The fact that this division occurs at a constant rate at the individual level is an assumption of your model. In particular, you assume that the random times between divisions of one agent are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Since agents "divide" independently, the probability of one reaction in the whole population is the sum of individual probabilities, thus the transition rate at population level is proportional to $n$,
$$W(n\to n+1)=\lambda n.$$
